# Webserver instance cant connect to mongodb instance using aws ec2 linux: Connection refused

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2

This is the first time using aws and linux.

I have setup a webserver with `export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app` and its works but when I separate my mongodb into another aws instance and changed the localhost to my mongodb instance private ip address its doesnt works anymore.

I use `telnet private-ip-add 27017` from webserver and it shows `Connection refused`

I have also set security group inbound on mongodb instance

> Custom TCP Rule   TCP   27017   webserver-private-ip-add/31

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Double-check the Security Group: Like you said, the EC2 instance must allow incoming TCP connections on port 27017 from either

   - the private IP network address other EC2 instance (e.g. `10.0.0.90/32`),
   - or better, the ID of the Security Group, that belongs to the other (accessing) EC2 instance (e.g. `sg-0d91740cb`).
2. Double-check the [MongoDB config](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) file: Option `net.bindIp` must not be set to `127.0.0.1` but the local IP of your MongoDB EC2 instance. You could also bind to "everything" (`0.0.0.0`), but this might be slightly less secure (e.g. if Security Groups are not set up properly).